# Get variables out of mako Template.render() objects in python?

Tags: python, templates, mako

Is there a way to get the variables from a Template object that was previously created with Template.render(...) in python? I couldn't find any getters in the docs...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question contains a wrong assumption:

> from a Template object that was previously created with
>   Template.render(...)

According to [the code](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/mako/src/285bc818a50ccc0f9549630f7c4f4c250585c3e7/mako/runtime.py?at=rel_1_0_0#cl-804), `Template.render()` or `Template.render_unicode()` return a byte string or a unicode object, respectively (no "Template object"!). In that case, there is no way to retrieve the variables used for rendering the template, that information is lost.

Comment: Thats good observation.. thank you! as a follow up, what does it meany by "callable" in """create a Context and return the string
    output of the given template and template callable."""